# Uploading an APK file using Powershell

Tags: powershell, file, upload

I have been trying to upload an APK file to a nodejs server. However the end result is not usable (61,8 MB) while the original file is (62,6 MB).

My idea is simple.

I want to run a powershell script to post an APK file to a Node JS server, which will write that file to a directory.

However, even though I am able to send the file, it gets corrupted during the way, and it seems to me to be most likely an encoding issue, but at this point, I have no clue.

This is my upload handler in my nodejs server:

```
app.post("/upload", (req,res) => {
  console.log('hello');
    let body = '';
    req.on('data', chunk => {
        body += chunk.toString();
    });
    req.on('end', () => {
      fs.writeFile(__dirname + '/uploads/my.apk', body,'binary',function(err) {
        if( err ) {
          res.end('not okay');
        } else {
          res.end('ok');
        }
      });
    });
});
```

This is my Powershell

```
$FilePath = 'dir\myApk.apk';

$URI = 'http://myUrl/upload';

$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $URI -Method Post -InFile $FilePath -ContentType "application/octet-stream";
```

Does anyone have a clue what's going on?

Comment: Why are you trying to re-implement `Invoke-WebRequest`?

Comment: I'm basing this on the Powershell script 'Upload to Hockey App' available in the Octopus Templates. Their agenda was speed no doubt. I get the same end result with Invoke-WebRequest.

Comment: Try the various TransferEncoding methods for Invoke-Webrequest?

Comment: @Scepticalist Whenever I set the TransferEncoding property I get "Unable to write data to the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine." Have you ever used these?